# Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Server$WorkerThread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

My chat program was working fine in my system when i changed the IP and compiled in my system. Then I copied the class file into another and it worked fine in that system, too. However, when the client sends a message it gives the following error :

`Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Server$WorkerThread`

I am using Windows 7. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a file named *Server$WorkerThread.class*. If you create one inner class in a *.java file, the compiler will generate two *.class files (one for the enclosing class and one for the inner class). The name of the inner class name will be prefixed by the enclosing class's name and seperated by a *$* character.

**Edit**:
Something I should add (I guess): Java loads classes *lazily*. This means that the jvm does not load the `Server$WorkerThread.class` until it's really required. The first time its code is needed is (no surprise I think), when the server wants to create an instance of aforementioned class to manage the communication with a client.

You may want to have a look at e.g. *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Joshua Bloch, where he advocates against the usage of the *Double Checked Locking Idiom* for thread-safe Singletons. It's a more elaborate example/explanation.

Comment: is this related to jre because am just installed jdk. my program is compiled in32 bit os running in 64 bit but i never think that this is not an issue.

Comment: jre/jdk does not make a difference here in terms of 'running a java program'. Both contain the (same) jvm, but the jdk brings additional tools (javac, javah, visualvm, etc.). It does not matter if you compile your code on a 32 or 64-bit os. The compiler will create the same (Java-)bytecode. The first part of my answer has to do with the compiler (The '$' stuff - happens at compile time). The second part was about how the jvm handles class loading (happens at runtime)